# Sails.js: Can I package some services/models as npm and load the npm in Sails.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I want to create two different Sails.js app such as hello-world and hello-world-admin. In two app, I want to make two apps use same services/models. So I'm thinking that packaging services/models in hello-world app as a npm, and loading it in two.

But Sails.js models must be extended accordingly in lifting phase. So just using 'require' doesn't satisfy it at all. Is there any correct/good way to achieve it (using same models in two app)?

I'm thinking using hooks to extend models but I couldn't find good example. Any comments/info would be appreciated.

### Updated

I'm trying to use "installable hooks" to extending models. I prepared sails-hook-models package in node_modules which has index.js below.

```
module.exports = function(sails) {

    return {
        defaults: {
        },
        initialize: function(cb) {

        var ModelA = require('./models/ModelA');
        ModelA.identity = 'modela';
        ModelA.globalid = 'ModelA';

        var ModelB = require('./models/ModelB');
        ModelB.identity = 'modelb';
        ModelB.globalid = 'ModelB';

        sails.models['modela'] = ModelA;
        sails.models['modelb'] = ModelB;

        return cb();
    },
};
```

After Sails has lifted, the models have been extended by waterline so I can call Model's method via sails.models['modela']. I'm not sure this is a good way.. Please tell me if you have alternatives / better ways.

Comment: you should show what have you tried

Comment: I'm trying to use installable hooks, pls take a look at Updated section above.

Comment: have you checked these docs: http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and there is a way to do this already: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-generate-entities. You define a manifest of which services/models/controllers/etc you'd like to install.

An example is here: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions

Comment: Travis, Thanks. sails-generate-entities allows us to generate services/models/controllers/etc which inherits super classes in specific npms, right?

is this below auto generated controller via sails-generate-entities?
https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/blob/master/api/controllers/AuthController.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [Sails Generator](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-generator) project to do this.